# Neo4j REST Encoding

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

I'm using neo4jclient. When I try to create/update an node, special chars like äöü are replaced with �.
Do I have to set a specific http header like content-type, content-encoding? If yes, what kind of header and what is the value of this header?

Thanks.

EDIT:
This is how the request looks like:

```
POST http://...........:7474/db/data/batch HTTP/1.1

Accept: application/json;stream=true

User-Agent: RestSharp 103.1.0.0

Content-Type: application/json

Host: ............:7474

Content-Length: 267

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate


[

  {

"method": "POST",
"to": "/node",
"body": {
  "Name": "äöü",
  "State": "Active",
  "Id": 0,
  "CreateDate": "2012-07-12T18:48:45.3343526+02:00",
  "ChangeDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00+00:00"
},
    "id": 0
  }
]
```

Or is it bug in the batch execution? If yes, I'll need the fix very quick:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Now it works**

After analyzing the messages.log we found out, that the file.encoding wasn't utf-8.

--> DEBUG [neo4j.diagnostics]: file.encoding = **Cp1252**

So we set in the neo4j-wrapper.conf file this property:

wrapper.java.additional.3=**-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8**

Now it works!!! :)

Thanks to my brother! Always good to know a Java developer. :)

Comment: This helped me find a problem running unit tests for a neo4j project on Mac OS, where messages.log said `DEBUG [neo4j.diagnostics]: file.encoding = MacRoman`. As this was using neo4j temp embedded, rather than edit a non-existent `neo4j-wrapper.conf`, the fix was to add this config to `maven-surefire-plugin`: `<argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>`

Comment: This thread may also be useful: https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/rabbithole/issues/25

Answer (score 0):

There are tests for this in the codebase, so it should be handled correctly, see https://github.com/neo4j/community/blob/master/server/src/functionaltest/java/org/neo4j/server/rest/BatchOperationFunctionalTest.java#L322 . However, there might be encoding problems in the client?

Comment: Okey. I did some tests with fiddler and had the same problem again. So it's not an neo4jclient problem, or an problem in my client application. 
Very strange..

Comment: Downloaded today the newest neo4j version but still the same problem (with my application and with fiddler too).

Comment: Could you try to get the raw JSON requests extracted and post them to the Neo4j user mailing list to track this down?