# How to store UNICODE data in neo4j?

Tags: rest, neo4j, cypher

I am trying to integrate neo4j in my project. Since my project is C++ based so I will be using REST API with cypher query language. Now, the problem I am facing is that in my project all the strings and data are UNICODE (Utf-16). So, I want to know whether neo4j supports UNICODE data??? And if yes, then how to insert using REST API + cypher query language???

Thanks

Comment: I want to say you'll have to convert to UTF-8, but I'm not entirely sure about that. Maybe it will accept UTF-16. Can you try setting the header encoding?

Comment: Is there anything that makes you need UTF-16 ? Java internally handles unicode quite well. So it might just be an issue of the content-type + charset header.

Comment: @WesFreeman: converting from UTF-8 to UTF-16 while storing and then again converting to UTF-16 while retrieving will be very costly task. This service will be running on a server, so it has to be very fast. The conversion will simply add an overhead.

Comment: @MichaelHunger: I did set content-type:application/json; charset = Utf-16, but in response I am getting error 500 Unexpected character '.'. And If I set charset as Utf-16 also, then I guess cypher query have to be in Utf-8. So, then it will be a mix charset, query in Utf-8 and data in Utf-16.

Comment: Where and how do you set the content-type?

Comment: @MichaelHunger: I am setting content-type in HTTP header. This is my HTTP header:
POST /db/data/cypher HTTP/1.0
Content-Type: application/json; charset=Utf-16
UNICODE: YES
CONTENT-LENGTH: 75

Comment: Might this Q/A help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11454352/neo4j-rest-encoding